What size is the loop antenna for 12.288 MHz?
I would like to know, what the size is for loop antenna driven with 12.288 MHz. I researched many pages on internet, but I want to know just the calculation which is being performed. Below a picture of my working antenna. I tested it with several quartz oscillators packed within AM modulators. What would the efficiency of this antenna be, for example configured with 20cm diameter and 12.288MHz frequency? What must the diameter be for full efficiency in this case?


@clvrmnky, Dereck: Search engine results have been personalized for at least 15 years by now. And so, you can't expect the first page of search results to be identical, or even close, to the one that someone else sees for the same search terms. It's fair to say "your search engine should find that", but quite honestly, a lot of the results are bad and and so, whenever I say that, I strive to also supply a link to a good page, because beginners have no way of telling good from bad. This isn't only a matter of kindness, it's a matter of being helpful at all!

as said, it is absolutely my experience that whenever I use google on the account of someone non-technical, the first page of results for technical queries are pure garbage. A simple link, your top result, would be the right thing to add when telling people to "just google it".

I use this one:
https://www.66pacific.com/calculators/small-transmitting-loop-antenna-calculator.aspx
Good luck and have fun!

